# appreciate + present continuous

Tags: tenses, present-progressive

I want to ask someone to send me some information and I think that I have those two options:

a) I would appreciate you sending me this information.

b) I would appreciate if you sent me this information.

My feeling tells me to use a) but I don't really know what kind of structure that is. b) is obviously a regular conditional clause type 2, so that's a safe bet. But what are the rules of a)? The present continuous is used to express actions that are taking place currently, but here it's considered more like a desired action that will take place some time in the future. Is this sentence correct? If so, why is that?

I would appreciate someone shining a light into the darkness of my grammatical despair.

Comment: "You sending me this information" in a) does not belong to the syntactic category of  present progressive (continuous) aspect, but to the semantic category of aspectuality. The difference is that the former is formed of "be" + _-ing_ complement, while the latter is not.